# Python iterator: use every consecutive entry as start and end

Tags: python, python-3.x, rrule

I want to find the weeks between two dates and iterate over them. I would like to have every consecutive entry as start and end. For instance, the list with indexes 0,1,2,3,... , I will have start date is the content of index 0 and end date the content of index 1. The second iteration, I will have the start date as the content of index 1 and the end date as the content of index 2, etc.

Here is my code thus far:

```
Weekly_date_list=list(rrule(DAILY, dtstart=datetime(2001,1,1),until=datetime(2002,1,1)))
```

If I loop over it, I will get the start date only.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can zip the list of dates with itself but of one index apart. For example:

```
dates = [datetime(2001,1,1), datetime(2002,1,1), datetime(2003,1,1)]
for start, until in zip(dates, dates[1:]):
    Weekly_date_list=list(rrule(DAILY, dtstart=start, until=until))
```

is equivalent to:

```
Weekly_date_list=list(rrule(DAILY, dtstart=datetime(2001,1,1), until=datetime(2002,1,1)))
Weekly_date_list=list(rrule(DAILY, dtstart=datetime(2002,1,1), until=datetime(2003,1,1)))
```